# WebActivatorEx vs OwinStartup

Tags: asp.net, web, owin

In a WebAPI application for example, what is the difference between

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyClass), "MyMethod")]
```

and

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(MyClass), "MyMethod")]
```

?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

They both are similar at a high level in the sense that they allow you to carry out initialization of your web application, but they are different in some important ways as below:

1. Methods targeted by `WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute` will execute before the Application has started up. This allows you to do things like injecting an HttpModule etc.
2. Methods targeted by `OwinStartupAttribute` will execute after Application has initialized. This is because this kind of startup is invoked by `OwinHttpModule` which in itself is injected in using `System.Web.PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute`.
3. Owin startup can be disabled via configuration by using an appsetting within web.config of `owin:AutomaticAppStartup`
4. There is also `System.Web.PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute` which as of .NET 4.5 can be used multiple times within an assembly.

So to summarise, this is the order of execution of methods depending on the attributes used.

1. `System.Web.PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute`
2. `WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute`
3. Global.asax (`Application_Start` method)
4. `OwinStartupAttribute`

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20561196/signalr-calling-client-method-from-outside-hub-using-globalhost-connectionmanage):

> In new SignalR API not using WebActivatorEx anymore.
>   **OwinStartup preferred instead of WebActivator**.

Comment: Not a good answer. Your question was "what is the difference between" and then you don't explain the difference in your answer.