# SignalR callback does not trigger in JQuery UI widget

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, jquery-ui, signalr

I am trying to create a JQuery UI widget that receives realtime updates from a server using SignalR (2.2.0). Invoking a method on the server works just fine, however invoking a client callback from the server does not trigger on the client.

I have enabled logging on the client as is suggested here: [SignalR Troubleshooting](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting) and I can see in the console that the connection is setup just fine but the client method is never invoked. There is no error message of any kind. I have also defined the client method on the hub proxy before starting the connection like so:

```
_bindClientCallbacks: function () {
    theHub.client.broadCastToClient = function (message) {
        twr.log(message);
    };
}
```

and afterwards I start the hub connection like so:

```
_startSignalRClient: function () {
    $.connection.hub.logging = true;
    $.connection.hub.start()
        .done(function () {
            twr.log("Connected to SignalR hub, id=" + $.connection.hub.id);
        })
        .fail(function () {
        });
}
```

These methods are called in the '_create()' function in the JQuery widget like so:

```
_create: function () {
    theHub = $.connection.DataImportHub;
    this._bindClientCallbacks();
    this._startSignalRClient();
}
```

This works fine and I can get a valid connection with an id. I can also call a server method from the client. But when I try to invoke the `broadCastToClient` method on the client from the server like so:

```
public void BroadCastToClient(string userId, string message)
{
    var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<DataImportHub>();
    foreach (var connectionId in _connections.GetConnections(userId))
    {
        hubContext.Clients.Client(connectionId).broadCastToClient(message);
    }
}
```

Nothing happens on the client.. even though the server does find a valid connection that corresponds to the connection id I got on the client.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Ensure that `_bindClientCallbacks` is called before `_startSignalRClient`...

Comment: I call the _bindClientCallbacks before the _startSignalRClient in the _create function of the JQuery UI widget (I added the function to the post for clarification).. so I don't think that's the problem

Comment: `hubContext.Clients.Client()` cannot be resolved on my machine, try `hubContext.Client()` instead.

Comment: The IHubContext interface only exposes properties Clients and Groups, so I cannot call Client() on it. I tried sending the message to hubContext.Clients.All but that also does not trigger the callback..

Comment: Just a question why don't you use `huContext.Clients.All.broadCastToClient(message);` ?

Comment: @Mathieu Because this would send the message to **all** clients.

Comment: @Mathieu Yes. I am performing a task for a specific user on the server and the updates I am sending to the client are only relevant for that user

Comment: @lange Try the SignalR stuff in a simple `<script></script>` section first. Your code looks ok to me, it should work.

Comment: Sorry I was in error due to the foreach, my bad

Comment: putting everything in a simplified <script></script> block yields the same result. Connection is fine, calling server method is fine, calling client method fails again.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out the solution by reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20561196/signalr-calling-client-method-from-outside-hub-using-globalhost-connectionmanage/20582574#20582574). Apparently having a custom SignalR dependency resolver setup in the Owin startup class breaks javascript callbacks. Moving the dependency resolver setup code to Application_Start in Global.asax does the trick. Why this happens really is beyond me...

**Bad DI setup in Startup.cs**

```
app.Map("/signalr", map =>
{
    var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
    {
        Resolver = new NinjectSignalRDependencyResolver(new StandardKernel())
    };
    map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
});
```

**Good DI setup in Global.asax**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = new NinjectSignalRDependencyResolver(new StandardKernel());
}
```