# Integrating notifications/messages to the client in an AngularJS + ASP.NET Web API app

Tags: sql-server, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm creating a SPA application with AngularJS at the client side and ASP.NET Web API as backend. My database is SQL Server 2012. There will be users which have a favourite sports team and a simple icon in the UI displaying the number of new articles/news/comments added or whatever connected to their favourite teams.

**What I'd like to achieve is the following:** Whenever a record about their team is inserted (record with TeamID column value for example equal to the user's favourite team ID), that notifications count icon should be updated **immediately** (just like Facebook's notifications - it's updated when a friend has posted on your wall or has tagged you and so on). How can I best achieve this?

What I'm thinking of for now is just setting an interval function in AngularJS to check every 30 seconds, let's say, if there are new records in the database making a request to a Web API controller. Of course this suggests a lot of checking for when the user is logging out - when was the last check, what will be the date to check against next time he/she logs in and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [signalR](http://signalr.net/) for this. It's a framework for real time communication. Check out [this](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20) to get if you want to get started. It can easily be used together with angularJS.

Comment: Yes SignalR is what you want to use. We use it for a very similar requirement than the original question.

Comment: Thanks I will have a look a that, I hope it will integrate with Web API somehow and achieve that 'on record insert' event that I'm looking for. :)

Comment: You can also talk from within the WebApi Controller to a signalR hub. This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695975/calling-signalr-hub-from-webapi-controller-issues) might give you some hints.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [push](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_push)

Sadly i never used it so i don't know much about it, but i think you should use technologies like [pusher](http://pusher.com/)

Comment: Thank you, I've heard about push notifications before and know what they are, but haven't used them in an application.