# How to send a message over a SignalR connection from Web API controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I see several examples such as [this](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) where the messages are sent from a hub using javascript. How can I send a message over this same connection from my c# code?

Specifically, I hit a post method in my web api controller and I would like to send a message over the SignalR connection from this controller. Is this possible?

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        // Call the addNewMessageToPage method to update clients.
        Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);
    }
}
```

and then in my Web Api post method:

```
  ChatHub hub = new ChatHub();
  hub.Send("testName", "test message");
```

All the examples I have seen send these messages from the javascript. This is my first time using SignalR. Can I send a message from the web api controller like this?

Thank you very much for your time. Please let me know if I am being unclear or if you need any more information from me.

Comment: May I assume the hub is located in your webapi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your hub is located in your webapi:

```
var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
hubContext.Clients.All.send("name", "message");
```

See also [calling SignalR hub from WebAPI controller issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695975/calling-signalr-hub-from-webapi-controller-issues)

Comment: what if hub is different app, I got two apis, once of them starts hub and when I call a method in other api, would like to send message to all subscriber of the hub started by first api.